# PHP function on JS Click?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a button that will copy a link to the clipboard but it has been shortened using bit.ly. At the minute I have it so that it creates the bit.ly link on page load which seems a bit messy so I just wondered how I can make it only do it when it copies to the clipboard?

```
var client = new ZeroClipboard( document.getElementById("copy-link"), {
moviePath: "ZeroClipboard.swf"
} );

client.on( "load", function(client) {
// alert( "movie is loaded" );

    client.on( "complete", function(client, args) {
        // `this` is the element that was clicked
        $.gritter.add({
            // (string | mandatory) the heading of the notification
            title: 'Link Copied',
            // (string | mandatory) the text inside the notification
            text: 'Link has been copied to your clipboard'
        });
        $('[data-toggle="dropdown"]').parent().removeClass('open');
    } );
} );
```

This is my PHP

```
<?php

$url = Router::url(null, true);
if ($this->UserAuth->isLogged()) {
    $url .= '?shareref=' . $var['User']['id'] . '';
}
$shortlink = bitly_v3_shorten($url, 'bit.ly');

?>
```

Answer (score 2):

JQuery Ajax will be your best option: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/ - Create it so that it runs the PHP when you click the button.

Comment: Yup. Ajax; ajax all the way :)

Comment: Perhaps you can add to your answer a wee bit to provide some sample code and direction. As his PHP is currently written, a variable will be assigned, but then nothing else. He would want to either echo `$shortLink` for a raw response, or enclose it in some json structure and return that in the response.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript can be like this

```
// Java script

jQuery("copyButton").click(function() {

    jQuery.ajax({
         type : "post",
         dataType : "json",
         url : 'urlshortener.php',
         success: function(response) {
            if(response.type == "success") {
                var shorturl = response.short;
            }
         }
    });
});
```

PHP looks like this, maybe its good to be protect it by XHTTP referees etc..

```
// PHP 

$url = Router::url(null, true);
if ($this->UserAuth->isLogged()) {
    $url .= '?shareref=' . $var['User']['id'] . '';
}
$shortlink = bitly_v3_shorten($url, 'bit.ly');


$result['type']= "success";
$result['short'] = $url;
$result = json_encode($result);
echo $result;
die();
```

Comment: Thanks, but how is the variable passed through of the url?

Comment: The example above don't need variable to post to php (url created on php i guess at least i thought so... if you need to pass var to php via jquery, in jQuery.ajax definition you need to add data : {variable:value} , data is the name of the parameter you send to php, value is the value of it..